# Java Рефлексия изменить не модифицированную переменную на public static

Tags: java, рефлексия

я читал про рефлексию в Джава, да у меня получалось менять с public static final на public static, но можно ли как нибудь изменить не модифицированный без public, private на public static

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через рефлексию вы можете получить досуп к описанию класса и модифицировать поля объектов этого класса косвенным образом. Но вы не можете модифицировать сам класс! setAccessible() отключает проверки доступа во время выполнения только для локальной копии описания поля, но никак не меняет класс. Так что удалить старые или добавить новые поля в класс, сделать поле статическим или наоборот - всё это совершенно невозможно.